# Help on the Earth Stone quest!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I got the quest called, "The Skaal Test of Loyalty" to make complete the rituals by going to each Standing Stone in Solthstiem [Bloodmoon]. I went to the Earth Stone and got a mission to, "Go northeast to The Cave of Hidden Songs and listen to its music". So I went to the barrow and went all the way to the stalagmites and stalactites. I got my journal updated, and activated them to get the journal updated twice. I look in it and it says it made music. I didn't know what to do next, figured I would go back to the stone. be when I got there and activated it, nothing happened! it was supposed to glow. I guessed I didn't "Listen to its music yet". But I don't what to do next with those hanging rocks in the barrow! Someone help me!

Comment: I could help you out if you told the actual name of the quest. Take a looksie in your journal.

Comment: @user1337 Okay it's called The Skaal Test of Loyalty. I edited it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to activate the stones in an order that mimics the sound you hear in the cave. Do this once, and the order of the notes should change. Do it a second time with the new tune, and you should be able to go back to the Earth Stone and activate it. Source: [UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Bloodmoon:The_Ritual_of_Earth)

Comment: Yep, this is what you have to do